# Why does adding #element_validate give warning about invalid callback?

Tags: forms, 9

I have code that adds `#element_validate` to all fields of a certain type (Link fields).

```php
$form[$field_name]['widget'][0]['#element_validate'][] = '_fix_link_field_value';
array_unshift($form[$field_name]['widget'][0]['uri']['#element_validate'][0], '_fix_link_field_value');
```

This works fine, but I get this warning in the logs every time an entity with this field type is saved.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm() (line 282 of E:\www\Noah\pre\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator.php).

I suspect this is because the existing validator has the format [class, method]. Is there any way to mix these validator formats?

Answer (score 3):

`#element_validate` expects an array of validation callbacks.

A callback can either be the function name of a globally accessible function, or an array of a class name and method name.

Now I am supposing that `'_fix_link_field_value'` is the name of a globally available function defined in your module.

So for using it as a validation callback, there is no array required here.

While the first line of your code is adding this callback to the callbacks of `#element_validate`, the second line is prepending it to an existing callback array, resulting in the following '#element_validate' value:

```
[[
  '_fix_link_field_value',
  (class),
  (method),
]]
```

Which won't work. You'd need:

```
[
  '_fix_link_field_value',
  [
    (class),
    (method),
  ]
]
```

So what you really want to do is to remove the trailing `[0]` from your `array_unshift` call:

```
if (!empty($form[$field_name]['widget'][0]['uri']['#element_validate']) && is_array($form[$field_name]['widget'][0]['uri']['#element_validate'])) {
  array_unshift($form[$field_name]['widget'][0]['uri']['#element_validate'], '_fix_link_field_value');
}
else {
  $form[$field_name]['widget'][0]['uri']['#element_validate'] = [
    '_fix_link_field_value',
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks and yes, that makes sense and pretty I tried that. Will try it again.

Comment: Yes, that was it, and i also did try that already. My problem was my validator function was not correct; but oddly enough when (as shown above) i was also adding the validator to the widget (incorrect) as well as the uri part of the widget (correct) the 2 mistakes seemed to give the desired result - but with the warning which I had not seen until now. Thanks again for having me take another look at it.